# Generate SAS token using Key Vault in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault, file-storage

Is there any way we can generate SAS token (to access the file storage) using Key Vault?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for. There are code examples as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: What do you mean `Generate SAS token using Key Vault`

Answer (score 0):

Key Vault is not used to generate a SAS token. SAS generation is a well-doc'd algorithm that uses one crypto primitive - an HMAC, but that's nothing to do with KV. The Storage Account SAS alg is available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas